# How to get all items that has added action but wasn't deleted

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an **Activity** table in which user's activity on actions is stored.
There is two type of actions in column type that are required to check:

- *add_favorite*
- *remove_favorite*

So same object can be added or removed from favorites multiple times so table has records like:

```
| id | type            | timestamp  | object_id | user  |
|----|-----------------|------------|-----------|-------|
| 1  | add_favorite    | 1584150783 | 4         | user1 |
| 2  | add_favorite    | 1584151341 | 5         | user1 |
| 3  | remove_favorite | 1584161259 | 4         | user1 |
| 4  | add_favorite    | 1584168758 | 4         | user1 |
| 5  | remove_favorite | 1584171635 | 10        | user1 |
| 6  | add_favorite    | 1584174201 | 11        | user1 |
| 7  | remove_favorite | 1584177194 | 5         | user1 |
```

First I was constructing two queries that was collecting all object_id's with add_favorite actions for the user in array. Then I was filtering this array with another one set of object_id's which had type of action removed_favorite

```
SELECT object_id FROM activity WHERE user='user1' AND type='add_favorite';
SELECT object_id FROM activity WHERE user='user1' AND type='remove_favorite';
```

But this is highly ineffective on large number of activities. Please advise me query with LEFT JOIN which would be more effective and will give the end result

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you are aiming for: Get a list of `object_id`s that do not have a remove action, the last action (by timestamp) by user, or some aggregate of the action by user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify your query to:

```
SELECT object_id
FROM activity
WHERE user = 'user1' AND
      type IN ('add_favorite', 'remove_favorite');
```

Then I would recommend aggregation:

```
SELECT object_id
FROM activity
WHERE user = 'user1' AND
      type IN ('add_favorite', 'remove_favorite')
GROUP BY object_id
HAVING SUM(type = 'add_favorite') > SUM(type = 'remove_favorite');
```

This gets the objects that have net more adds than removes.

An alternative is to look at the *last* action and only choose those that are adds:

```
SELECT a.object_id
FROM activity a
WHERE a.user = 'user1' AND
      a.timestamp = (SELECT MAX(a2.timestamp)
                     FROM activity a2
                     WHERE a2.user = a.user AND
                           a2.type IN ('add_favorite', 'remove_favorite')
                    ) AND
      a.type = 'add_favorite'
```

With an index on `activity(user, type, timestamp)`, this probably has better performance.

Comment: Aggregation you suggested as 2nd option works 3 times faster rather then option suggested by @wp78de ( Query took 0.0025 seconds vs Query took 0.0008 seconds). But it's giving some object_id that shouldn't be there The last 3rd option suggested from you works very accurately and gives the result in 0.0025 seconds. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquery like this

```
SELECT object_id
FROM activity a1
WHERE a1.user = 'user1'
AND a1.type = 'add_favorite'
AND object_id NOT IN (
    SELECT object_id
    FROM activity
    WHERE user = 'user1'
        AND type = 'remove_favorite'
    )
```

However, I guess you want a list of effectively active (added) favorites

```
SELECT a1.object_id
FROM activity a1
WHERE a1.user = 'user1'
    AND a1.TIMESTAMP = (
        SELECT MAX(a2.TIMESTAMP)
        FROM activity a2
        WHERE a2.user = a1.user
            AND a1.object_id = a2.object_id
            AND a2.type IN (
                'add_favorite'
                ,'remove_favorite'
                )
        )
    AND a1.type = 'add_favorite'
```

Here is a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/291f2bb/19).

Comment: The first query would not work cause it will not include object_id's added and removed multiple times. Second one seems to work, I have to test it. Thank you!

Comment: I checked it out on my table and it gives more id's than it should :(